# Ninja Forms 3.0 On Form Load javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ninja-forms

I'm trying to find a javascript event that gets fired when a ninja form is ready and is loaded in the DOM.

I looked over the documentation and searched around google for a while, couldn't find anything...

I'm using Ninja Forms 3+ (even though 2 was a hella lot better....)

I'd rather not have an interval running to check if the form has been loaded yet.

Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

Unfortunately the pretty Ninja Forms plugin is not documented properly. Spent much time before I found this solution (using jQuery):

```
jQuery(document).on( 'nfFormReady', function() {
    console.log('Form is ready');
    // Place events handlers here:
    jQuery(".contact-form input[type=button]").on('click', function(){
        console.log('Do something');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer. You're right, the plugin documentation is terrible! Do you happen to have a theory as to why a function to disable scrolling within a number field would work in normal forms (via a good ol' e.preventDefault) but the same function fails in a Ninja form? I wonder if it's related to your answer somehow -- i.e. perhaps I need to tap into some other NF-specific event? Here's a simplified version of my function: `document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("wheel", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });`

Comment: It's pretty much non-existent.  Your time has helped me, thank you.

Comment: It's now 2020 and the `nfFormReady` seems to only be documented here. Thanks!